# a close shot in music video (fisheye ? prob. not )

Tags: cinematography, music-video

I was watching this music video, and my question is about the shot at minute 1:04 -> 1:06, where he leans into the camera and the background seems with no movements.

Does this effect have a name?

Comment: This looks like a question for https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Sandun Questions about the cinematography of music videos are on-topic here. I have a feeling Music Fans would just kick it back over here.

Comment: @F1Krazy Ok no worries then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like they're using a zoom lens to create the effect, combined with a pan and move in then out.

If you look at the whole shot, they start with [I'm guessing] a 35mm focal length. As he walks out of shot to get in the vehicle, they zoom wider to [again guessing] 18mm or so; then as they swing round to find him in the car the camera just moves towards him. There's a point at which it looks like the camera hits something - probably intentional as part of the look & feel - then they pull back [move the camera away again] as he leans into the lens.

18mm isn't wide enough to really be classed as a fish-eye, but if you're really close to it you do get a hint of that effect - big nose, little ears.

[image]

<sup>The lens lengths have to be guesswork, as we don't know what format 'film' [sensor size these days for digital] they are using.</sup>